# Is EPiServer threadsafe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, episerver

I can't find any information about this on either www.episerver.com or world.episerver.com, anyone knows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thread safe is a nebulous concept.  In this particular case, if you are sharing data between different requests, it is not.  Otherwise by the nature of web requests it is.

Answer (score 9):

From what I've seen Episerver uses two mechanisms to achieve thread-safety:

- Locking (when initializing expensive resources)
- Immutable data (when passing page data around)

Comment: I also like how EPiServer handles database deadlocks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, per definition it is thread safe because it runs under a web service that uses threads to execute (so it has to be thread safe otherwise it is a bug, and there has been o few of those bugs – but no one reported for CMS R2 what I can see in the bug list).